# Google Directions API and traffic-based rerouting

Tags: google-directions-api

I was wondering if Google Directions API automatically reroutes if traffic is heavy on a route like Google Maps itself does, or if it will always return the same route, regardless of traffic?

If it does reroute, is there a way to force it to always return the same route?

Thank you :)

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have all information you need on this webpage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=us

Under the subchapter "Optional Parameters", there is parameters like: `alternatives`, `traffic_model`

I guess this webpage is very useful and I hope it will help you :)